# pysimplegui Is there posible to add value to input and print it in windows

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I would like to get value+2 in window after i input my number. i tried to to it that way but i dont understand how one variable is dic and str and diffrent time. Thats what i tried using pyspysimplegui example.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Text('x+2=:'), sg.Text(size=(15,1), key='-OUTPUT-')],
    [sg.Input(key='-IN-')],
    [sg.Button('Show'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

window = sg.Window('Pattern 2B', layout)

while True:  # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Show':
        print(type(event), values)

        values += '2'

        window['-OUTPUT-'].update(values['-IN-'])

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got an event `Show` generated when you click on button `Show`, then `window.read()` in your `while True` event loop will return a 2-tuple, `(event, values)`.

- `event` is the event when `window.read()`, `'Show'` here.
- `values` is a dictionary with `key:value` of some elements, `{'-IN-': ''}` here.
- The value of an Input element is in `str`, not int or number.
  Refer [Return Values](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#return-values)

Revised code as

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Text('x'), sg.Push(), sg.Input('', key='x')],
    [sg.Text('x+2:'), sg.Push(), sg.Input('', disabled=True, key='x+2')],
    [sg.Button('Show'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

window = sg.Window('Pattern 2B', layout)

while True:  # Event Loop

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

    elif event == 'Show':
        x_string = values['x']
        try:
            x = int(x_string)
            y = str(x + 2)
        except ValueError:
            y = "Wrong number !!!"
        window['x+2'].update(value=y)

window.close()
```